# Get these icons in-line rather than a column?

Tags: html, css, inline

I am new at html I'm trying to create a footer for my website. My task at school requires us to make a website using html and css. I decided to use little social icons as it looked good aesthetically and it was a pretty accessibility feature. However, when I added the logos it decided to sit in one column rather than in line with each other:
[image]

Here's the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="copyright">
  <div class="copyrightlogo">
    <h1>Ⓒ Jared's Workshop 2021</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="copyrighticons">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/JaredWorkshop" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/logos/twitter.png" style="width: 50px;"/>
    <a href="https://discord.gg/a3mSUZdv" target="blank"><img src="./assets/logos/discord.png" style="width: 50px;"/>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8QDFSoKcS7xOyphNKMPOhw" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/logos/youtube.png" style="width: 50px;"/>
  </div>
  <div class="copyrightmessage">
    <p>
      All Rights Reserved. Copyright 1991-2021 Jared's Workshop Pty Ltd (ABN: 48 051 046 596). The Jared's Workshop Logo & Mouse Pointer in Circles are registered Trademarks of Jared's Workshop Pty Ltd. All other trademarks and copyrights are the property of their respective owners. For further information on terms of service & conditions please see Terms & Conditions. Core Inside, Intel, Intel Logo, Intel Core, Intel Inside, Intel Inside Logo, Pentium, Pentium Inside, vPro Inside, Xeon, Xeon Phi, and Xeon Inside are trademarks of Intel Corporation in the U.S. and/or other countries.
      This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google Privacy Policy and Terms of Service apply.
    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* FOOTER */

.copyright .copyrightlogo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.copyright .copyrightlogo h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.copyright {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:50px;

}

.copyright p{
  color: white;

  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.copyright .copyrighticons {
  padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.copyright .copyrighticons img{
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add display: inline-block; to copyright a it would make them look in one line

Answer (score 1):

You could also use flexbox:

```
.copyrighticons {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex for it

```
   .copyrighticons{ display: flex; justify-content: center; align-content: center;}

.copyrighticons a{margin: 0 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!! Was playing around with the CSS and found that if I added:

```
.copyright .copyrighticons a{
display: inline-block;
}
```

it would fix my problem!
Here's what it looks like now:

[image]